# Prove existence of inverse of a bounded linear operator

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, hahn-banach-theorem

Exercise 5.17 (Hunter and Nachtergaele) Suppose that $K: X \rightarrow X$ is a bounded linear operator on a Banach space $X$ with $\|K\|<1 .$ Prove that $I-K$ is invertible and
$$
(I-K)^{-1}=I+K+K^{2}+K^{3}+\ldots
$$
where the series on the right hand side converges uniformly in $\mathcal{B}(X)$.

My approach: I think we should use open mapping theorem in some form because it talks about inverses? But then we need to show the inverse exists instead of saying something about boundedness of the inverse, which is what open mapping theorem does, so I'm a bit confused.

Comment: As an aficionado of series-based reasoning, I'd think about first showing that the series converges meaninfully and uniformly in $\mathcal{B}(X)$, and then verifying that it has the algebraic properties of an inverse (which may require more theorems about series, hopefully some of which you can take for granted). There may be other approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Just verify that the series $\sum_n K^{n}x$ converges for each $x$ using completeness of $X$ and the fact that $\|K^{n}x\| \leq \|K\|^{n} \|x\|$. Then define $Tx =\sum_n K^{n}x$. Uniform Boundeness Principle gurantees that $T$ is a bounded operator: Apply the theorem to the sequence of operators $(T_n)$ where $T_n (x)= \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} K^{i}x$. Now it is an easy matter to verify that $(I-K)T=T(I-K)=I$ so $T$ is indeed the inverse of $I-K$.

Comment: You can directly verify that $\sum_n K^n$ is a Cauchy sequence in the operator norm.

Comment: @daw Yes, but instead of assuming that the space of bounded opeartors is complete (which may not be known to OP) I thought of using completeness of $X $.