# find $f \in L^2(0,1)$ such that $f = g + K(f)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces

I'm preparing for my qualifying exam and the question bank had the following question under functional analysis section and I'm stuck with this problem.

Let $L^2(0,1)$ be the Hilbert space of square integrable functions on the interval $[0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure. Define $K : L^ 2 (0,1) \rightarrow L^ 2 (0,1)$ by $K(f)(t) =\int_0^t (t − s)f(s)\,ds$. Show that
$||K|| < 1$. Given $g \in L^ 2 (0,1)$ find $f \in L^ 2 (0,1)$ such that $f = g + K(f)$.

My idea for the second part of the problem: I feel like it is the kernel of some map and that the question is asking to find an element in the coset of $g$ (the coset that you get after you quotient out by the kernel).

I really have no idea how to proceed. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please edit the question. This will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Don't you mean $K(f)(t):= \int_{0}^1 (t-s)f(s)ds$ ?

Comment: @Brozovic Why do you think that?

Comment: Can you show that $\|K\|<1$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Yes that I could.

Comment: @JackyChong Cause I'm working on $L^2(0,1)$ and would love to use convolution maybe

Comment: @Brozovic My comment was for OP's consumption. The question lacks context and such questions are not supposed to be answered.

Comment: @Brozovic If we take $u(t)=\int_0^t(t-s)f(s)ds$ then our functional equation $f=g+K(f)$ turns into the differential equation $$u''-u=g(t)$$ which has solution $$u(t)=\frac{e^t}{2}\int_0^te^{-s}g(s)ds-\frac{e^{-t}}{2}\int_0^te^sg(s)ds$$ Taking $f=u''$ seems to work (click on link), but I don't know if this is a valid approach since we may not be able to assume that $u$ is twice differentiable. https://www.desmos.com/calculator/x1fn8rf7q7

Comment: @MatthewPilling That precisely was my point of looking at $K(f)(t):=\int_{0}^1 (t-s)f(s)ds$ rather than $K(f)(t):=\int_{0}^t (t-s)f(s)ds$ as the former then is just $K(f)=f* \text{ id }$ and as the underlying measure space is finite, being able to apply DCT, we actually get that u is indeed $C^{\infty}(0,1)$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy as I said I really don't understand how to find the required $f$. But I have some intuition and so I have edited the post and mentioned my intuitive idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the proof for the first part , I'll try for the second part.
$||Kf||_{L^2(0,1)}=(\int_{0}^1 |Kf(t)|^2 dt)^{\frac{1}{2}}=(\int_{0}^1 |\int_{0}^t (t-s)f(s)ds|^2 dt)^{\frac{1}{2}} \le \int_{0}^t (\int_{0}^1 |(t-s)f(s)|^2dt)^{\frac{1}{2}}ds$ The inequality appears by Minkowski's integral inequality.
Now the last term $=\int_{0}^t (\int_{0}^1 |(t-s)|^2dt)^{\frac{1}{2}}|f(s)|ds$ As translations give isometry on $L^2(0,1)$  and letting $id :(0,1) \to (0,1)$ be $x \mapsto x$

we have, $$\int_{0}^t \Big(\int_{0}^1 |(t-s)|^2dt \Big)^{\frac{1}{2}}|f(s)|ds$$ $$=\int_{0}^t ||id||_{L^2(0,1)}|f(s)|ds$$ $$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\int_{0}^t|f(s)|ds$$ $$\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} ||f||_{L^1(0,1)}$$ $$\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} ||f||_{L^2(0,1)}$$ Thus $$||Kf||_{L^2(0,1)} \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} ||f||_{L^2(0,1)} \implies ||K|| <1$$

Answer (score 3):

Answer for the second part: $\|K\|<1$ implies that $I-K$ is invertible and its inverse is $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} K^{n}$. [See my answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4021302/prove-existence-of-inverse-of-a-bounded-linear-operator/4021335#4021335 ]

Hence, the unique solution of $f=g+Kf$is $f=(I-K)^{-1} g$.

Answer (score 1):

There is another way to prove the second statement. Since $K: L^2\to L^2$ for a given $g\in L^2(0, 1)$ you can define a map $T_g: L^2(0, 1)\to L^2(0, 1)$ by
$$T_g(f)=g+K(f).$$
If you show that $T_g$ is a contraction mapping, since $L^2$ is a complete metric space then by the Banach Fixed Point Theorem there exists a unique fixed point $f\in L^2(0, 1)$ of $T_g$, that is
$$f=T_g(f)=g+K(f)$$
which is the solution you are looking for. This is indeed the case, since
$$\|T_g(f_1)-T_g(f_2)\|_{L^2}=\|K(f_1)-K(f_2)\|_{L^2}\leq \|K\|\|f_1-f_2\|_{L^2}$$
and you already proved that $\|K\|<1$.

**EDIT:** If you want to compute $f$ explicitly, you can go as follows (i'll skip any technical detail). First we write the equation as
\begin{align}f&=g+t\int_0^1 f(s)ds-\int_0^1sf(s)ds\\&=g+C_1t-C_2\end{align}
where
\begin{align}C_1&=\int_0^1f(s)ds,\\ C_2&=\int_0^1 sf(s)ds.\end{align}
Then by replacing $f$ in $C_1$ we get
\begin{align} C_1=\int_0^1 (g(s)+C_1s-C_2)ds=\int_0^1g(s)ds+\dfrac{C_1}{2}-C_2\end{align}
and then
$$\dfrac{C_1}{2}+C_2=\int_0^1 g(s)ds.$$
Similarly by replacing $f$ in $C_2$ we get
$$\dfrac{C_1}{3}-\dfrac{3C_2}{2}=-\int_0^1 sg(s)ds.$$
With these two equations we can obtain $C_1$ and $C_2$, hence by replacing it in the first equation for $f$ you get the full expression only in terms of $g$.

Answer (score 1):

There is an easier way prove the first part of this statement using the Cauchy-Swartz inequality. Let $f\in L^2[0,1]$ be arbitrary, and define $g\in L^2[0,1]$ by $g(x)=1-x.$ Notice

\begin{eqnarray*}
|K(f)(t)|^2 & = & \Bigg(\int_0^t(t-x)f(x)dx\Bigg)^2
\\ & \leq & \Bigg(\int_0^1(1-x)f(x)dx\Bigg)^2 \\
 & = & \Big|\big<f,g\big>\Big|^2 \\ & \leq & ||f||^2||g||^2 \\ & = & \frac{1}{3}||f||^2
\end{eqnarray*} Therefore,

$$||K(f)||^2= \int_0^1|K(f)(t)|^2dt \leq \frac{1}{3}||f||^2$$ Hence $||K||\leq \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}<1$.