# Continuous dependence on initial conditions of Fredholm integral equation of the second kind

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, integral-equations

In several papers and other sources, I have seen statements about it being `well-known' that the [Fredholm integral equation of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fredholm_integral_equation#Equation_of_the_second_kind) is [well-posed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-posed_problem), in contrast to a Fredholm integral equation of the first kind. I'm looking for some precise statements that an equation of the form

$$f_i(t)=g_i(t)+\int_a^bK_i(t,s)f_i(s)\ \mathrm ds,\quad i=1,2,$$

has a solution depending on the initial conditions in a continuous manner. In other words, we expect something like: given $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ s.t. $\|g_1-g_2\|,\|K_1-K_2\|<\delta$ $\implies$ $\|f_1-f_2\|<\epsilon$. With respect to which norms do those results hold true? Is this true in $L^1,L^2,L^\infty$? Or even in any $L^p$ space, $p\in[1,\infty]$?

The only result in this spirit that I was able to find is Theorem 2.6.1 from Zemyan, The Classical Theory of Integral Equations, A Concise Treatment, Birkhauser, which deals with $L^\infty$ spaces. However, I'm particularly interested in the $L^1$ case, and where we are able to drop continuity assumptions on the initial conditions. Does such a result hold as well if we use $L^1$ norms?

**EDIT** It seems that Corollary 3.12 of Gripenberg, Londen, Staffans, Volterra Integral and Functional Equations provides a positive answer to my question.

Any help or reference is much appreciated.

Comment: You may want to apply a fixed point theorem (check in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4024041/814741) for instance). It is done in $L^2$, but with that given, you can think what happens on the other cases.

Comment: If I'm not mistaking, this is about the existence and uniqueness of solution, but not about the continuous dependence on initial conditions, which is what I'm interested in